# How to switch a L10N Bundle in running state in CN1

Tags: localization, codenameone

How can I switch the language and refresh the gui in the running state of my application (without having to restart the application)? I already know how to affect the gui components which contain keys from a managed l10n bundle in a `initVars` call but not how to do it afterwards.

I'm using the following 2 lines to determine the bundle initially:

```
Map h = res.getL10N(L10N_BUNDLE_NAME, lBundleKey);
UIManager.getInstance().setBundle(h);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to refresh a `Form` that's already created as the values were already extracted from the bundle. Apps that do that recreate the `Form` e.g. if I have a method such as `showSettingsForm()`, I'd just invoke it again when changing the language and it will update the Strings.

Comment: ok I see. The recreation of the form should be done in the main application class right? Is there any example demonstrating a form recreation?

Comment: ok I managed it by calling `showForm` from `StateMachineBase`

Comment: If you are using the old GUI builder you can use `reloadForm()`